# iphone login with validation

Tags: ipad

I want to create a login application for iphone. I want to store the user name and password somewhere. Which database can be used for this? Please share the code which checks the username and password entered in the textboxes against the database fields. Plzz help

Answer (score 0):

[NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). All contained data is available only from your application.
Example [here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/).